# OCaml Printf.printf - missing output mystery

Tags: ocaml

The following code...

```
type 'a osResult =
  Success of 'a
| Error of string


let errorCatcher f =
  try
    let result = f () in
    Success result
  with Unix.Unix_error (code, fun_name, arg) ->
    Error(String.concat ":" [(Unix.error_message code); fun_name; arg])

let my_getcwd () = 
  errorCatcher (fun () -> Unix.getcwd ())

let _ =
  print_endline "The Start";
  let result = my_getcwd () |> function
  | Success folder -> Printf.sprintf "getcwd:\n\t%s\n" folder
  | Error errMessage -> Printf.sprintf "getcwd (error):\n\t%s\n" errMessage
  in
  print_string result ;
  print_endline "The End."
;;
```

...compiles fine:

```
$ corebuild -tag debug test1.native
```

...and runs fine:

```
$ ./test1.native 
The Start
getcwd:
        /home/ttsiod/work/byePythonHelloOCaml
The End.
```

But if I change the main body to this:

```
let _ =
  print_endline "The Start";
  my_getcwd () |> function
  | Success folder -> Printf.printf "getcwd:\n\t%s\n" folder
  | Error errMessage -> Printf.printf "getcwd (error):\n\t%s\n" errMessage
  ;
  print_endline "The End."
;;
```

... then apparently the last print statement ("The End") gets lost or something...

```
$ ./test2.native 
The Start
getcwd:
        /home/ttsiod/work/byePythonHelloOCaml
```

Initially, I thought this is a case of stdout buffering not being flushed.

But the docs of `print_endline` clearly claim that it flushes stdout, so I am at a loss - and adding "flush" didn't help, either:

```
let _ =
  print_endline "The Start";
  my_getcwd () |> function
  | Success folder -> Printf.printf "getcwd:\n\t%s\n" folder
  | Error errMessage -> Printf.printf "getcwd (error):\n\t%s\n" errMessage
  ;
  print_endline "The End." ;
  flush stdout
;;
```

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `print_endline` is treated as part of the `Error` case. From the indentation, this is clearly not what you meant, but unfortunately the OCaml compiler doesn't warn about this.

You can use `begin` and `end` (or just parentheses) to make it work:

```
let () =
  print_endline "The Start";
  my_getcwd () |> begin function
  | Success folder -> Printf.printf "getcwd:\n\t%s\n" folder
  | Error errMessage -> Printf.printf "getcwd (error):\n\t%s\n" errMessage
  end;
  print_endline "The End." ;
  flush stdout
```

Alternatively, without using `;`,

```
let () =
  let () = print_endline "The Start" in
  let () = match my_getcwd () with
    | Success folder -> Printf.printf "getcwd:\n\t%s\n" folder
    | Error errMessage -> Printf.printf "getcwd (error):\n\t%s\n" errMessage
  in
  let () = print_endline "The End." in
  flush stdout
```

Comment: Thanks! By the way, as you can probably guess from the folder name I am working in - "byePythonHelloOCaml" - your blog posts have won at least one convert :-)

Comment: The tool that I expect to warn me when I make this mistake is Emacs+Tuareg mode, which indents `print_endline "The End."` so as to show that it belongs to the case above.

Comment: (and using `|>` to send a value through an anonymous function may be a little too cute for its own good. Just because you can write this does not mean that you should)

Comment: @Pascal: I am in "re-learning-OCaml-mode", so all bets are off :-) In my defense though, the normal "match my_getcwd () with | Success -> Printf ... | Error  -> Printf  , I would have still faced the same error. I wish OCaml spotted this - a warning would have sufficed :-(

Comment: @ttsiodras I realize this and I tried to express that no combination is incorrect—unless it is syntactically incorrect or does not type. Have fun!

Comment: I've always tried to limit my use of `;`, even for the sake of a line of `let () =`. The `let () =` doesn't add much visual overhead, and reduces the number of `begin ... end` blocks (which I favor over parens).

Comment: @nlucaroni: Can you show an example of how the code would look with 'let () = ...' constructs? I tried to use it but failed ("syntax error"). A gist would suffice...

Comment: My guess is you didn't include the `in`. `let () = <expr> in`.